# I want to disable all the default controls of video element and to build my own controls

Tags: video, element

when I use video element, I will have the option to download the video and view in PIP and adjust volume etc. But I want to get rid of all elements except play/pause, slider and fullscreen toggles. Would this be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You hide the regular video controls and display your own ones.

Mozilla have an exam please including code here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player

As an example, just having a play button can be done like this:

```html
<video id="yourVid" width="640" height="480">
    <source src="yourPath/yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<span id="your-play-button">Play</span>
```

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("yourVid");
var playBtn = document.getElementById("your-play-button");

playBtn.click(function () {
            vid.addEventListener('ended', endOfVidHandler,false);
            vid.play();

            //Hide the button when oplaying
            playBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";

            //Show the button again at end of video
            function endOfVidHandler(e) {
                playBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });
```